# Handling urllib2's return of badstatusline(line)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, return, urllib2

I've got a simple internet checker running but it occasionally returns an error what I can't seem to handle...

Here's the function:

```
def internet_on():

    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("http://google.co.uk/", timeout = 10)
        return True
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        return False
    except socket.timeout as e:
        return False
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Testscript.py", line 117, in internet_on
    urllib2.urlopen("http://google.co.uk/", timeout = 10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 442, in error
    result = self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 629, in http_error_302
    return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 1045, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 409, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 373, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
BadStatusLine: ''
```

How can I handle this error to return false, I'm wanting the internet_on function to return true if it connects but if anything other than true it should return false..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import httplib

...


def internet_on():
    try:
        urllib2.urlopen("http://google.co.uk/", timeout = 10)
        return True
    except (IOError, httplib.HTTPException):
        return False
```

Comment: Is that overwriting my other two parts (timeout and urlerror)?

Comment: `tiemout`, `URLError` is subclass(directly/indirecly) of `IOError`.

Comment: `BadStatusLine` is subclass of `HTTPException`.

Answer (score 3):

```
except httplib.BadStatusLine as e:
    return False
```

Comment: What would be the difference in function between this one and the one falsetru posted?

Comment: Nothing - you can use separate `except` statements if you want to handle different exceptions differently, but if you want to do the same thing for all exceptions, you can just list them in a tuple as @falsetru did.